Unit Test case for if statement inside service in angular
I have a service (Service 1)  which internally returns data from another service(Service 2). So we do a data check in our Service 1 before we return data.
 `getuserImageUrl(Id: number): Observable<string> {
        return this.getUserDetailsAPI(Id)
          .pipe(
            map((userInfo: any) => {
              console.log(userInfo);
              let url = userInfo.url;
              if (url === undefined || url === null) {
                return '';
              }
              return url;
            })
          )
          .pipe(
            catchError((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              return '';
            })
          );
      }`

I have tried the following, but in code coverage it say that the if block in service is not covered . How to cover this if block in unit test
it('should provide null if image url is null', fakeAsync(() => {
    userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI.and.returnValue(of(""));
    userService.getuserImageUrl(Id)
      .subscribe((data) => {        
        expect(userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(data).toEqual('');
      });

      const req1 = httpTestingController.expectOne(
        `myproject.com/getuserImageUrl/${Id}`
      );
      expect(req1.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req1.flush("");
      
  }));


Write a test case using the values it checks for?!

Positive scenario
it('should provide url if image url is present', fakeAsync(() => {
    userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI.and.returnValue(of({ url: 'test' }));
    userService.getuserImageUrl(Id)
      .subscribe((data) => {        
        expect(userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(data).toEqual('test');
      });

      const req1 = httpTestingController.expectOne(
        `myproject.com/getuserImageUrl/${Id}`
      );
      expect(req1.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req1.flush("");
      
  }));

Negative scenario
it('should provide empty string when url is undefined', fakeAsync(() => {
    userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI.and.returnValue(of({ url: undefined }));
    userService.getuserImageUrl(Id)
      .subscribe((data) => {        
        expect(userServiceSpy.getUserDetailsAPI).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(data).toEqual('');
      });

      const req1 = httpTestingController.expectOne(
        `myproject.com/getuserImageUrl/${Id}`
      );
      expect(req1.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req1.flush("");
      
  }));

